# Draw on achartengine on touch

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

i'm trying to compare two values from two series at the same X value from the chart below:

[image]

i can get the values with .getCurrentSeriesAndPoint() but it is not really usable
is it possible with the current achartengine api to detect touch on blue area and draw black rectangle around those two values?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: and just draw the black rectangle?

Comment: There is a requirement to draw custom graphics on the chart. I think I will add this feature as a plugin at some point.